# Time Diff on vertical dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df that looks like this

```
 Date               Value

 10/1/2019          5
 10/2/2019          10
 10/3/2019          15
 10/4/2019          20
 10/5/2019          25
 10/6/2019          30
 10/7/2019          35
```

I would like to calculate the delta for a period of 7 days

Desired output:

```
Date         Delta

10/1/2019    30
```

This is what I am doing: A user has helped me with a variation of the code below:

```
 df['Delta']=df.iloc[0:,1].sub(df.iloc[6:,1]), Date=pd.Series 
 (pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp('2019-10-01'), 
 periods=7, freq='7d'))[['Delta','Date']]
```

Any suggestions is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try `shift`

```
s = df.set_index('Date')['Value']
df['New'] = s.shift(freq = '-6 D').reindex(s.index).values
df['DIFF'] = df['New'] - df['Value']
df
Out[39]: 
        Date  Value   New  DIFF
0 2019-10-01      5  35.0  30.0
1 2019-10-02     10   NaN   NaN
2 2019-10-03     15   NaN   NaN
3 2019-10-04     20   NaN   NaN
4 2019-10-05     25   NaN   NaN
5 2019-10-06     30   NaN   NaN
6 2019-10-07     35   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this- is there a way to only show the date and delta columns?

Comment: @Lynnette out = df[[''Date',DIFF']].dropna() :-)

Comment: Hi- It is saying: Not supported for type Index  ---do I need to convert Date to datetime?

Comment: @Lynnette adding `df.Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
` before run